# error with insert into from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, insert

i'm new here and i have a question.

I am trying to insert a row into my MySQL database via Java.
for the java part i use Netbeans.

when i run it i get the following error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES01234567PietdeBakker0113605040java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFields' at line 1

the code i came up with is the following from DBObject.java:

```
 public void insertDeelnemer(Deelnemer d){
   String sql = "INSERT INTO deelnemer(OVnummer,Voornaam,Tussenvoegsel,Achternaam,Telefoonnummer,Geboortedatum) VALUES" + d.getOvnummer() + d.getVoornaam() + d.getTussenvoegsel() + d.getAchternaam() + d.getTelefoonnummer() + d.getGeboortedatum();
   try{
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

which goes with this from DeelnemerToevoegen.java:

```
String OVnummer = OVnummerVak1.getText();
String Voornaam = VoornaamVak1.getText();
String Achternaam = AchternaamVak1.getText();
String Tussenvoegsel = TussenvoegselVak1.getText();
int dag = DagComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()+1;
int maand = MaandComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
int jaar = JaarComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()+1980;
GregorianCalendar Geboortedatum = new GregorianCalendar(jaar, maand, dag);
String Telefoonnummer = TelefoonnummerVak.getText();
Deelnemer d = new Deelnemer(OVnummer, Voornaam, Achternaam, Tussenvoegsel, Geboortedatum, Telefoonnummer);
DBObject dbo = new DBObject();
dbo.insertDeelnemer(d);
```

Comment: Remember Bobby Tables... http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Stop messing about and use a parameterised query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a space between `VALUES` and `"`. This should be `VALUES " +`. Also, all values need to be comma-separated and strings need to be quoted using a single quote ('). That's what you get for not using parameterized queries...

**EDIT**
Additional tip: Look at Adrian's SQL statement. Unless the content of your `sql` variable looks like that if you print it to the console, you're not providing valid SQL.

Comment: so i put it like this: `String sql = "INSERT INTO deelnemer(OVnummer,Voornaam,Tussenvoegsel,Achternaam,Telefoonnummer,Geboortedatum) VALUES " + d.getOvnummer(), d.getVoornaam(), d.getTussenvoegsel(), d.getAchternaam(), d.getTelefoonnummer(), d.getGeboortedatum() + ;` when i do that netbeans say ; expected for  all the d.get-ers

Comment: No, you put it like this: `String sql = "INSERT INTO deelnemer(...) VALUES ('" + d.getOvnummer() + "', '" + d.getVoornaam() + "', " + ... + ");";`. Just mind the basics of Java syntax. There's a stray `+` before the `;` and you still don't have correct SQL syntax.

Comment: i see, i get the follow error now: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,len' at line 1. any way to fix that..?

Comment: Yes. Your last value in the query is supposed to be a `DateTime` value. The way you're doing it, Java adds a string representation of the *object* to the string, not the string representation of the *date*. Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to generate a string from the date...

Comment: My brain is farting right now sorry, can you put down a little example..? im just a beginner, started with java less then 4 weeks ago.

Comment: does this work when you use 3 drop-down boxes, one for day, one for month and one for year..?

Comment: This is not a problem of getting the date of birth from the user. The problem is that you're not providing a string where you must. I posted a link yesterday where they show you how to turn a date object into a string like "2012-03-31". Unless you understand how to do this and why it is necessary, you'll not be able to send your query to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around your values list as well as a comma between each. And probably quotes around each value too.

Answer (score 1):

You need brackets and commas for your values (and probably `"` for the string values):

This is the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `INSERT` is

```
INSERT INTO table ( column1, column2, ... ) VALUES( data1, data2, ... ) ;
```

The numbers of specified columns and data must match. And if you insert non numerical values you'll have to quote `'...'` the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your SQL string to a log, and you'll probably see that it's not really valid sql at all. You're just concatenating all the values right next to the word `values` which will make it something like

```
"INSERT INTO deelnemer(OVnummer,Voornaam,Tussenvoegsel,Achternaam,Telefoonnummer,Geboortedatum) 
VALUES12345JanDeVreis061234567804099180"
```

which is cleary NOT valid sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude ....

> String sql = "INSERT INTO
>   deelnemer(`OVnummer`,`Voornaam`,`Tussenvoegsel`,`Achternaam`,`Telefoonnummer`,`Geboortedatum`)
>    VALUES("+String.valueOf(d.getOvnummer())+","+String.valueOf(d.getVoornaam())+","+String.valueOf( d.getTussenvoegsel())+","+
>   String.valueOf(d.getAchternaam())+","+String.valueOf(d.getTelefoonnummer())+","+String.valueOf( d.getGeboortedatum())+")";